# Get index of element in set (STL C++) in asysmtotically less than O(n)

Tags: c++, data-structures, set, fenwick-tree

I have heard that we can use binary search along with Fenwick tree to do it in O(logn*logn) . We can also use PBDS to do it in  O(logn) . Can some one explain in detain how to do them . If there is some other way please tell that also.

Comment: I have knowledge of working of fenwick tree but i have no clue about PBDS .

Comment: Why don't you just throw all those terms at a web search and read a few of the results? What is the relation to C++, the STL or its `set` container? BTW, as a new user here, please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: The STL offers you a `find()` function for every data type, this is the most efficient and safe way to do so. Just search online how to use the `find()` function to find an element in a set.

Comment: `std::set` is typically implemented as a red-black tree. Theoretically, you can get element index in `log(n)` time if you store left subtree size in each node. `std::set` doesn't do it, so the best you can get with `std::set` is linear time.

Comment: Is the question "how to do it?", or "Which library I can use that implement this functionality?" (or something different). It seems like you already know how to implement it, and seems like you are aware this is not in the STL, so you'll either need some external library, or implement it on your own.

Comment: PBDS stores the size of a rooted subtree at it's root node. When searching for in index, it looks at this size to choose to go left or right. Also, Fenwick tree method can be done in `O(logN)` using the bit representation to maneuver left or right on the Fenwick tree. But the limitation of this method is that there should be no -ve elements in the input and the `max_element` in the input be sufficiently low so that you can allocated `sizeof(int)*max_element` size of memory for the Fenwick tree. Both implementations can be found online.